# Foreign key in tastypie

Tags: python, django, rest, tastypie

So, I started using the [TastyPie](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie) plugin for Django to make a REST api for my project. I was following the getting started guide with my project, but when I got in [this point](http://toastdriven.github.com/django-tastypie/tutorial.html#creating-more-resources), when I was supposed to put a Foreign Key, it started giving me some errors.

The maior one is this when I do a simple get:

```
"Reverse for 'api_dispatch_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': 246, 'api_name': 'v1', 'resource_name': 'typep'}' not found."
```

The code in the resources.py:

```
class TypeOfPlaceResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = TypeOfPlace.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'typep'
        allowed_methods = ['get']

class POIResource(ModelResource):

    typep = ForeignKey(TypeOfPlaceResource, 'typep')

    class Meta:
        queryset = PointOfInterest.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'pois'
        filtering = {
            "code1": ALL,
            "code2": ALL,
        }
```

And the models:

```
class TypeOfPlace (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class PointOfInterest(GeoInformation):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    code1 = models.CharField(max_length=4,null=True, unique=True)
    code2 = models.CharField(max_length=4,null=True, unique=True)
    typep = models.ForeignKey(TypeOfPlace)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

The urls.py

```
api = Api(api_name='v1')
api.register(TypeOfPlaceResource(), canonical=True)
api.register(POIResource(), canonical=True)

urlpatterns = api.urls
```

So, am I doing something wrong ? Or missing something ? Any help would be really appreciated ! :D

Comment: can you add your TastyPie URLconf?

Comment: Sure ! Just edited the main question :]

Comment: what url did you type that caused this problem? try changing `urlpatterns` value to `urlpatterns = patterns('', (r'^api/', include(api.urls)),)`

Comment: I tried a lot of urls combination that works when I don't use the ForeignKey in the POIResource. Like api/v1/pois/1. It returns every information from the POI but breaks in the typep attribute. I haven't set up the project in this machine yet, but I'll try your tip as soon as I do so. :]

Comment: Ok, it worked. Thanks ! But now I get 401 errors when trying to make PUT/POSTs .. :S

Comment: Not sure if you figured it out by now, but 401s on PUT/POSTs means you need to define an `authorization` in your `Meta` for the resource.

Comment: Thanks ! I've already found that one, but it's nice having the answer here if someone has the same doubt ^^

Comment: Thanks @manji . I had similar problem, when enabling custom url (ie. I don't like the 'v1' in the url). I think we have to be careful with url in Tastypie.
In addition, maybe you know how url are generated, ie. how to access custom url in the view ?

Comment: can one of you post the answer as an answer? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The final answer for my problem is the answer from @manji and @dlrust combined:

"change `urlpatterns` value to `urlpatterns = patterns('', (r'^api/', include(api.urls)),)`"

and, after that, "define an authorization in your Meta for the resource".

Hope it's useful for somebody else as it was for me :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `urlpatterns` might be getting overwritten.

```
urlpatterns += api.urls;
```

does adding the `+=` like this work? It seems that by assigning directly to `urlpatterns` you may be unexpectedly clobbering any old assignment you had.